# Why is this set of vectors linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\{-1+t,2+t^2,-3+t+t^2,-1-t-t^3,2+3t^2+t^3\}$$

Why is the above set of vectors linearly dependent? If i place it in a matrix and row reduce:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
        2 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
 Becomes 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Since the bottom row can be ignored, the only solution possible to this matrix augmented with 0, is that all the coefficients must be 0? Doesnt this mean that the set is linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place the vectors in a matrix, you place them as rows. You need the rows of your matrix to be linearly independent, but you check linearly independence for columns.

Note that since you get a row of zeroes, your rows are linearly dependent.

Comment: The wording here is a bit weird. Usually, you put vectors in a matrix as columns, and then check for linear independence of columns. The OP put the vectors in the matrix as rows, and so they need to check for linear independence of rows.

Comment: NS' approach is also fine, although I would agree with Ian (+1) that I also would put the vectors as columns. From a linear algebra standpoint, I don't think it makes a difference form the conclusion.

Comment: Well, you do have to pay attention, because a matrix can have linearly independent rows and not have linearly independent columns or vice versa. If you can reduce it to have a row of zeros then it has neither, of course.

Comment: So could i have constructed my matrix as the transpose of what it currently is? that would have allowed me to check for linear independence of columns rather of rows.

Comment: @rohaldb yes...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using matrices (which is formally the way to go), take a look from a different perspective; You have 5 polynomials, the highest degree is 3. Hmmmm, conclusion? Second, you cannot just "ignore" a row of zeros as if it isn't there. That would imply that you can never have an independent set in linear algebra?